# How can I put rich snippet codes in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying convert jQuery-based website to React-based website, and I need to use the below codes in Reactjs, but it seems like the format of codes don't work in Reactjs.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "https://www.example.com/",
    "potentialAction": {
      "@type": "SearchAction",
      "target": "https://www.example.com/search/?q={search_term_string}",
      "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
    }
  }
</script>
```

I researched about how to do that, but they all work with some third-party plugins from NPM. Since I'm still a beginner in React, can any one recommend what's the best way to put rich snippet codes in Reactjs?

Answer (score -2):

[JSON-LD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-LD) is supposed to be consumed externally, primarily by search engines.

`<script type="application/ld+json">` tag isn't related to the application itself and shouldn't be a part of React application, unless proven otherwise.

Comment: I used to put the code snippet directly on the html file, and it worked well. So, I expected it's gonna work well in React as well. Anyway so, should I use one of the third-party plugins? Can you recommend one for me?

Comment: It's a good idea to continue doing that. This snippet is supposed to be static because it's intended for search engines. Search engines won't render React app. Currently only Google is capable of rendering JS, and it's not doing great. If you want to generate this snippet dynamically, do this on server side.